# Facebook FQL error with getting my friend's photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am creating an applications that gets my friend's photos sorted by created date so I use the following FQL to get the photo.

```
SELECT src_big_width,src_big_height, caption, owner, pid, src_big , src_small ,aid, created FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())) 
    ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 0,1000
```

But I my profile I see some friend posting a new photo, but it does not appear in my 
profile. Is there any error or mistake in my FQL?

Answer (score 0):

Does your access token have the `friends_photos` permission? You need this to access the photos of a friend.

Also, check that you can see the photos in the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API)  by using the [Graph API explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to check there is data there which can be accessed via your access_token. This will help to rule out issues with your FQL query.